# Crop part of canvas into another canvas object

Tags: javascript, tinymce, html5-canvas

I have a PDF that is converted to a canvas object. I see many plugins that crop an **image** to a canvas object. What I need is to crop part of the PDF canvas into a new object.

Then eventually I will drop the new canvas into **tinymce** editor but I guess this is a second step.

Is there a ready to use plugin that can crop not only from images but from canvas objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the cropping parameters on canvas context.drawImage to crop one canvas into another canvas.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/kdHLU/

```
var cropX=80;
var cropY=0;
var cropWidth=80;
var cropHeight=140;
var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
canvas1.width=cropWidth;
canvas1.height=cropHeight;
var ctx1=canvas1.getContext('2d');
ctx1.drawImage(canvasPDF,cropX,cropY,cropWidth,cropHeight,0,0,cropWidth,cropHeight);
```